# Horizontal Scrolling with mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I have designed a horizontal website subdivided in items (both id# and .class). The JS allows me to scroll horizontally using the mouse wheel but I'd like either scroll in percentage (for example 50% left or right) or to the previous or next item.

```
$(function() {
$("#wrapper").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 100);
event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

TNX

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/) to scroll horizontally.
You can use this to jump to pages:

> To get the width of your html page you can use $(document).width();
>
> You can then divide this by the view-port's width using
>   $(window).width();. So:
>
> ```
> window.addEventListener("resize", pageResize);
>
> var pageResize = function(){
>     viewWidth    = $(window).width();     //no var to make the variable global
>     pageHeight    = $(document).width();  //no var to make the variable global
>     numberOfPages = pageWidth/viewWidth;  //no var to make the variable global
> }
> var goToPage = function(page){
>     window.scrollTo((page-1)*viewport, 0);
> }
> ```

Or to jump to an object, you can use:

> Just pass in the ID of the element you would like to jump to.
>
> ```
> var nav = function(l){
>     var left = $("#"+l+"").offset().left; //Getting X of target element
>     window.scrollTo(left, 0);
> }
> ```

You will have to adapt some of this code to work exactly the way you want with your webpage.

Not sure if this answers your question. If not, feel free to let me know so I can edit it.

Comment: sorry, where is the ID (#item) supposed to go?

Comment: You would use the function like this: nav(<enter ID here>)

Comment: First, make sure you don't have a #. Also make sure you are using quotes around the ID. For example: `nav("bigBox")` I am also going to update the code so it uses jquery more